# On delete restrict mysql is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-delete, referential-integrity

I want to prevent deleting from parent table when he has children in other tables that.

I make like this

```
ALTER TABLE constant_det_tb 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_idparent
FOREIGN KEY (idparent)
REFERENCES constant_tb(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

When I delete from parent constant_tb table, it delete the rows even the table has reference to another tables and it has records reference to it.

Comment: It enough to create ON DELETE RESTRICT foreign key. If it does not work - please provide full code (SHOW CREATE TABLE for both tables).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have InnoDB as storage engine for all affected tables.

Check this (if not already) : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

```
ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

reference option is all you need to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Checking of foreign keys could be disabled for current session.
It can be enabled with

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```